# Windows Reverse Engineering

Tags: security, reverse-engineering, malware

In the part of my malware analysis. I wish to learn more about windows malware reverse engineering. but I only have a little knowledge of reverse engineering. now I read some books related to reverse engineering. I need some resources for windows reversing and
windows reversing challenges for practicing. most of the websites have  Linux ELF-related challenges. As a beginner how can I start my windows reversing career? I don't know how to start? where to start? how can I improve my skill?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at CTF challenges. Especially those who are related to reverse engineering.

I can only recommend you [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwir7PaGz5D3AhXJPOwKHfEcB1cQwqsBegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8ev9ZX9J45A&usg=AOvVaw0Pn5EsdOiPMQZ8O9IPJprz) video if you want to learn more about CTFs

Here are some resources that might help you:

- [1](https://ctf101.org/reverse-engineering/overview/)
- [2](https://fareedfauzi.gitbook.io/practice-ctf-list/reverse-engineering)